# JavaScript create array with .map() with empty items (sparse array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Say I have an array

```js
[1,2,1,2,1];
```

I want to use `.map()` to return a new array which is the same as the old one but the item is missing in the new array if it was 2 in the old one. So the new array would be:

```js
const newArray = [1, ,1, ,1];
```

So the code would look something like:

```js
const newArray = [1,2,1,2,1].map(d => d === 1 ? d : "not sure how to return empty item here");
```

But I don't know what to return to make the array have a missing element.

edit: I suggested using `.map()` because I didn't realise it is not possible to go from an array to sparse array (as helpfully explained in their comment below). In this case a solution not using `.map()` is OK.

Comment: There is no such things as a "missing item" - at most you can put in `null` or `undefined` for such elements

Comment: Do you want a *sparse array*? Because you cannot use `.map()` to change from dense to sparse array as you're supposed to provide 1:1 mapping, whereas a sparse array has *less* items. However, you can use `undefined` as a marker for a missing value. Not sure what the use case for that would be, though.

Comment: Yes I want a sparse array (didn't realise what they were called before posting). This is a very helpful, thanks. In this case a solution without `.map()` is OK.

Comment: @UnholySheep That's not true. Unlike `a = [1, undefined, 2]`, with `a = [1, , 2]` your array `a` will not have any element `a[1]` whatsoever (`1 in [1, , 2]` will be `false`, and `a.map(console.log)` will only list elements `a[0]` and `a[2]`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `undefined`:

```js
const newArray = [1,2,1,2,1].map(d => d === 1 ? d : undefined);
console.log(newArray);
```

This is an example on how empty elements are treated in JavaScript:

```js
arr = [1,2,3];
newArr = arr.concat([, , , 5,6]);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: A "hole" can be accomplished like this, [1,2,1,2,1].reduce((a, v, i) => {
  if (v === 1) a[i] = v;
  return a;
}, [])

Comment: A sparse array is not the same as the value `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ That's true, but `undefined` is better than a non-existing property.

Comment: @Bergi I don't disagree. However, the answer leaves the impression that `[1, undefined, 2]` and `[1, ,2]` are the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

You could just return `null`:

```
const newArray = [1,2,1,2,1].map(d => d === 1 ? d : null);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const array = [1,2,1,2,1];
const newArray = Array(array.length);

array.map((item, index) => item !==2 ? newArray[index] = item : null);

// newArray -> [ 1, <1 empty slot>, 1, <1 empty slot>, 1 ]
```

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` to do simple iteration. You can use `.forEach` or a normal loop for that.

Comment: Also, don't create empty slots on purpose. This will make the array much slower to use.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it